# Dental modeling

Tags: modeling

Does Blender offer software for creating dental models? I am in need of designing and creating these models for 3D printing. The big corporations that offer this  service are inaccurate.

Comment: just like many other 3d softwares blender can create 3d models of almost anything though it does not specifically have something for dental models. if you decide to use blender i recommend sculpting because it is usually more organic looking. BTW welcome to blender

Comment: The software Blender does not have any tools specifically designed for creating dental models. There are addons which support the 3D printing process.

Comment: relevant https://www.blendernation.com/2018/03/13/liberteeth3d-another-add-on-for-orthodontics/ https://www.blendernation.com/2012/01/27/open-dental-cad/

Answer (score 2):

Blender is a 3D creation suite. It does not 'offer' any software, because it is a piece of software itself. Although not primarily intended for dental models, it should offer all necessary tools to create them.

However judging by your complaints about the inaccuracy of professional services, I guess you are trying to scan something rather than modeling it yourself? This can definitely not be achieved with vanilla Blender.

One general thing on a side note: If 'big corporations' are not capable of fulfilling a task to your satisfaction, you might be asking something, that is out of today's technical scope...